# Is there a way on Python to extract a time series from an image?

Tags: python, time-series

I am trying to extract a time series dataset from an image (with x-axis and y-axis). Is there a quick way to do so on Python?

To be more precise, this is my graph:
[HEL Share Price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqSt2.png)
and I am trying to get daily data.

Any help?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this Web App that can do it: [WebPlotDigitizer](https://apps.automeris.io/wpd/)

Looking at [alternativeto.net](https://alternativeto.net/software/webplotdigitizer/) I found [Engauge Digitizer](http://markummitchell.github.io/engauge-digitizer/) which "accepts image files (like PNG, JPEG and TIFF) containing graphs, and recovers the data points from those graphs" and a recent version "adds python support". I never used Engauge, but it sounds like what want...

Keep in mind, that it is not that easy to automate such a task, because finding the correct axis labels and "49,28" label even might overlap the graph sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you could try this [Python3 utility](https://pypi.org/project/plotdigitizer/). It says it can extract raw data from plots images.

But you can more easily extract data from graph images using GUI-friendly tools, like [plotdigitizer.com](https://plotdigitizer.com/) or [automeris.io](https://automeris.io/). I prefer the former over the latter. You can find the entire list of such programs over [here](https://www.saashub.com/plot-digitizer-alternatives).